# Conditionals within script. in jade

Tags: node.js, pug

In Jade, is it possible to create a conditional if statement in a dynamicscript section?

For example:

```
doctype html
html
 head
  script.
   -if( locals.display_JS )
    console.log("Display_JS is TRUE")
   -else
    console.log("Display_JS is FALSE")
```

(locals.display_JS is a parameter pass to Jade in res.render.)

If display_JS is true, the desired output should look like:

```
<script ...>console.log("Display_JS is TRUE")</script>
```

However the output is:

```
<script>
 -if( locals.display_JS )
  console.log("Display_JS is TRUE")
 -else
  console.log("Display_JS is FALSE")
</script>
```

It could be that I am thinking wrong. My objective is to render different javascript functions based on parameters sent to res.render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade will not mess with anything within a script block. If you really need to use jade logic inside a script block you can get a little tricky and do something like this:

Router Code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {run_this:true});
});
```

Jade Code:

```
div
| <script type='text/javascript'>
if(run_this)
    | console.log("Ran this!");
else
    | console.log("Didn't run this");
| </script>
```

Another approach to running logic based on jade variables within a script tag is to do something like this:

```
script.
    if(!{run_this}){
        console.log("Ran This!");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have noticed that !{} actually works in the script block. For example: I can insert the variable run_this using !{run_this}. If I could run the condition within the !{}, then it could work. However !{ if(run_this) { console.log("Ran this"); }} will generate an error.

Comment: That is another route you could take. It is a different approach than running jade conditionals within the script tags. I have updated my answer to include how that approach may work.

Comment: Great! Perhaps another question, but how does the !{} work anyway? For example !{ Math.Floor(25.5) } works, but !{ if( Math.floor(25.5) == 25) { return 25 } } does not work. It seems like you can do a limited set of javascript functions withtin !{}. But conditions, like if/for/while, produce errors.

Comment: {} doesn't allow you to run jade conditionals within the script tags. The brackets are what jade uses for escaping. Basically it inserts the value of whatever variable is inside the brackets right into the html document. In our case, it is inserting true/false right into the script block inside the javascript if statement. The ! ensures it doesn't encode any of the character that it is inserting. Look at the section on escaping here: https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/

Answer (score 2):

It can be done the other way, use the . whenever you want to nest javascript code.

```
doctype html
html
 head
  script
    if( locals.display_JS )
      .
         /** Some JS code **/
         console.log("Display_JS is TRUE")
    else
      .
         console.log("Display_JS is FALSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `script.`  everything that comes after will be interpreted as plain text by jade. If you need to mix markup and plain text you can use `|`. For example:

```
script
    | function bar(){
    if(true)
      | console.log("Ran this")
    else
      | console.log("Don't run this")
    | }
```